# WPF Border IsMouseOver trigger not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have defined this kind of style in app.xaml:

```
    <Style x:Key="RedCloseButton" TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="Yellow" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And I'm trying to use it in another xaml -file like this:

```
    <Border Style="{StaticResource RedCloseButton}" Name="ClearValue" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="black" CornerRadius="0,4,4,0" Margin="110,90,0,80" Background="#FF801F1F">                
            <Rectangle Margin="10,11,6,10" Fill="White" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" IsHitTestVisible="False"></Rectangle>
    </Border>
```

But nothing happens when I mouse over the border.. what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Its because you have set the `Background` in the `Border`, this will override the `Style`

You will have to remove `Background="#FF801F1F"` from the `Border` `xaml` so the `Style` can set the `Background`

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource RedCloseButton}" Name="ClearValue" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="black" CornerRadius="0,4,4,0" Margin="110,90,0,80">                
        <Rectangle Margin="10,11,6,10" Fill="White" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" IsHitTestVisible="False"></Rectangle>
</Border>
```